# Using mod_write for cleanurls with Lets Encrypt

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, encryption

I have enabled Let's Encrypt on a server running Apache on Ubuntu 14.04 and used the auto option to re-direct all http requests to https. This is working fine.

However, I now want to use mod_rewrite to use cleanurls on my site - all I need to do is remove the .php extension from all filenames. (e.g. https://example.com/contact routes to https://example.com/contact.php)

I have tried adding the following rewrite rule to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

This configuration works fine on my localhost setup (without SSL) but does not work on the instance running Lets Encrypt.

I have tested that the .htaccess is working by adding this rule which works as expected (redirecting all www requests to the root domain)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I suspect that there may be some conflict between the Lets Encrypt auto setup option and my mod_rewrite rule but I am stuck as to how to make them both work together.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does the "auto option to re-direct all http requests to https" actually do? How is the redirect achieved? Minor point (this won't actually change anything), but there is no need to escape the dot in the `RewriteCond` _TestString_ - this is an ordinary string, not a regex.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it adds the following to the sitename.conf Apache virtual hosts file `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sitename [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.sitename
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]`

Comment: The auto option has also created a second apache conf file named "sitename-le-ssl.conf"

Comment: And what's in that other conf file (a VirtualHost container for HTTPS I assume)? Presumably the redirect you posted is in the VirtualHost for port 80? It would be preferable for that redirect to canonicalise the host (ie. to non-www), otherwise you could potentially end up with two redirects if a user was to access `http://www.example.com`. Incidentally, the canonical www redirect you posted in the question redirects to HTTP (no S) - doesn't that result in a redirect loop (I guess not?!)?

Comment: You'll need to check what `REQUEST_FILENAME` is returning. You could save this in an environment variable and output this in your PHP code, or set a custom response header and check the network traffic? Enabling debug mode could also help... `LogLevel rewrite:trace6` (very verbose) - see [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel) for options.

Comment: I have checked what `REQUEST_FILENAME` is returning - it is the path to the filename (e.g.  [REQUEST_FILENAME] => /var/www/sitename/public_html/output.php) - I get the same result running on localhost just with a different filepath.

Comment: I have also enabled verbose logging as you suggest, and can see errors which relate to the rewrite. e.g. `RewriteCond: input='/var/www/sitename/public_html/output.php.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched` 

It seems that the .php file extenstion has been repeated - could this be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable `MultiViews` in `.htaccess`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) is likely resulting in a conflict. This does something very similar to what you are trying to achieve using mod_rewrite. With MultiViews enabled (possibly enabled in the server config, although the default is *disabled*), a request for `/filename`, will result in Apache *looking* for a file that matches (that would return the appropriate mime-type) by stepping through the files in that directory (essentially trying various extensions where the *basename* matches).

> I have checked what REQUEST_FILENAME is returning - it is the path to the filename (e.g. [REQUEST_FILENAME] => /var/www/sitename/public_html/output.php)

Yeah, that's the problem. MultiViews has already "fixed" the URL (`output` to `output.php`) before mod_rewrite has been able to do its thing.

Comment: That has fixed the issue, thank you. 

MultiViews (which I was not aware of) presumably also explain why the 'cleanurls' seemed to already work for .html files (without any mod_rewrite rules in place). It does seem odd though that MultiViews would work with one file extension and not another.

Comment: Yes, MultiViews would explain why the "clean" `.html` URLs _magically_ worked OK. The _conflict_ with `.php` URLs (that was ultimately breaking your site with MultiViews enabled - a 404 I assume(?)) is likely to have been "somewhere else". The mod_rewrite directive (in your question) to add the `.php` extension would have simply failed (because the preceding file check _condition_ would have failed). I assume your www to non-www canonical redirect would have "magically" redirected to the `.php` URL?